# Is frequency at normal inversely proprtional to wavelength?

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength

since speed of sound is constant for normal conditions(conditions where speed of sound is normal) , can anybody provide me the mathametical proof of why frequency is linearly and inversely proportional to wavelength of a sound wave.

Comment: If a wave pulse travels at a speed $v$ then it takes time $t=\lambda/v$ to travel one wavelength distance $\lambda$. Frequency is defined as $f=1/t=v/\lambda$.

Comment: @lemon
you are using the concept of constant speed arbitarily !

Comment: By definition of frequency and wavelength, they are inversely proportional. Whatever may be the wave, wavelength times the frequency gives velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound in air satisfies the d'Alembert equation $(\vec{\nabla}^2 - \frac{\partial^2}{c^2 \partial t ^2}) f(\vec{r},t) = 0$. As far as sound is concerned, you are looking for a superposition of harmonic plane waves of the form $f(\vec{r},t) = A \exp(i(\vec{k}.\vec{r} - \omega t))$. Putting this function inside of the d'Alembert equation gives you the dispersion relation $\omega = k c$, which you can re-write as $\lambda f = c$.

Comment: what is w and k in the dispersion relation you mentioned

Comment: $\omega = 2 \pi f$ is the pulsation of the wave and $k = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$ is called the wavevector. The dispersion relation is the equation linking this two quantities.

Comment: I guess the OP hasn't studied waves yet.

Comment: You're probably right, but I don't know of any rigorous mathematical proof without using this kind of formalism.

Answer (score 1):

By the very definition of frequency and wavelength, they are inversely proportional.

The wavelength is defined as the distance between two consecutive maxima or minima and the frequency is defined as number of wavelengths that are crossed per second.

Therefore,

$\lambda f = v$   where $\lambda$ is the wavelength, $f$ is the frequency and $v$ is the velocity.

In most of our day to day problems, the velocity remains constant. Hence, you can write the above equation in an alternate form as

$\lambda \propto \frac{1}{f}$